# Format piecewise function inline with text

Tags: formatting

I am still relatively new to TeX.  Thank you in advance for your patience with me.  I assure you I have looked around for more than just 5 minutes before asking this question.

I am able to create a piecewise function using the following:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
....
\question %7
Let \begin{equation*}
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
          x, & x < 3,\\
          4x, &  x > 3
          \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
be a function.  Which of the following statements is/are true about $f$?
...
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

However, the piecewise function is centered awkwardly on its own line when really I just want it inline with the rest of the sentence.

In other words, the above gets me

"Let

(centered) f(x)= look-at-all-my-pieces

be a function..."

and I would like it to be
"Let f(x)= look-at-all-my-pieces be a function..."

I can do this with a non-piecewise function by simply using $f(x)=function-stuff$ but I am unable to do this once I have cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

  \question
  Let $ f(x) = \begin{cases}
      x & \text{if }x < 3 \\
      4x & \text{if }x > 3
    \end{cases}\, $
  be a function. Which of the following statements is/are true about $f$?

  \question
  Let $ f(x) =\left\{ \begin{matrix}
      x & \text{if }x < 3 \\
      4x & \text{if }x > 3
    \end{matrix}\right.\, $
  be a function. Which of the following statements is/are true about $f$?
  \question
  Let $ f(x) = x$ if $ x < 3 $, $f(x) = 4x $ if $ x > 3 $, be a function. Which of the following statements is/are true about $f$?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't `f` be inside the math `$` expression?

Comment: Probably. I guess my mouse slipped while I was asleep. I'll fix that in a while. Thanks for pointing it!